# Flask Python Logging: TypeError while logging file path in File

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to add content of variable "log_location" to current logger.

```
log_location = log_folder_location + os.path.sep + log_file_name
logger.debug("log location", str(log_location))
print "log_location: ",log_location
```

this prints to console, but gives error in logging,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 784, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 662, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 444, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 314, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

it prints to,

```
log_location:  /U01/Nova/Logs/DEV-INT/TEST/validation_20170203-164617-5.log
```

This error is not happening in when I try in normal python prompt
but facing same when using Flask

I've tried [Logging Python stdout to File... with active stdout (backspacing/updating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947029/logging-python-stdout-to-file-with-active-stdout-backspacing-updating)
and [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python)
and this one too [Python: Logging TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843099/python-logging-typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting)

But did not understand what to do. Can someone explain this using simpler language, not like the documentation?

Comment: What Python version are you using? maybe there are unicode issues? what type are log_folder_location and log_file_name?

Comment: I need your logger settings, probably this would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use only one argument to `logger.debug()` method call. I.e.

`logger.debug("log location: " + str(log_location))`

About the autoformatting feature (I don't think you need this, but for the completeness sake) - let's look from the docs:

> Logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Logs a message with level DEBUG on this logger. The msg is the message format string, and the args are the arguments which are merged
>   into msg using the string formatting operator. (Note that this means
>   that you can use keywords in the format string, together with a single
>   dictionary argument.)

So, multiple arguments are useful when you have formatting template in the first arg, for example

`logger.debug('log location: %s', log_location)`

Comment: Yes, this was the right way, in fact I used logger above this code, & forgot to remove " , ", when changing print stmts to logger.debug..Now I think about it, I feel stupid to ask this...but yes, Thanx a lot this solves the issue(tested).